# Urban airship production configuration

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

What is the best way to switch the inProduction variable that needs to be set to true for production build in AirshipConfig.properties for the Urban Airship android SDK?

Is there something I can configure in gradle or am I left to manually switch the file before prod build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave out inProduction from you AirshipConfig.properties file, the SDK will try to auto detect the flag for you by checking the BuildConfig.DEBUG flag.

Alternatively, you can use [build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) to provide different versions of the config.